# Scraping <div> inside a <div>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble scraping the names of a `<div>` that are already in a `<div>` (It works with complete other part even though I tried to search for a specific card-body)

https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500

I need this part:

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
   <div class="row no-gutters py-1 px-3">
      <div class="col col-lg order-lg-1 text-nowrap text-ellipsis">
         <a href="/name/example" translate="no">example</a>
```

Even though I find names, they are not from the list I want. Does anybody know how to locate them?
Im using **beautifulsoup** and **lxml**. Part of my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html_text = requests.get('https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
itemlocator = soup.find('div', class_='card-body p-0')
for items in itemlocator:
print(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script should produce the available names that you see in that page. However, it seems you are only after the container in which `Commander` is available. In that case, you can try like below to get the desired portion which is concise and efficient compare to your current attempt.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?sort=asc&length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=500'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

html_text = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text,'lxml')
item = soup.select_one(".card-body > .no-gutters a[href^='/name/Commander']")
item_text = item.get_text(strip=True)
datetime = item.find_parent().find_parent().select_one("time").get("datetime")
print(item_text,datetime)
```

Output:

```
Commander 2021-03-19T13:10:40.000Z
```

Comment: You're still not getting names like `Commander` etc.

Comment: Okay, look for it within the output that I've pasted above.

Comment: Is there any way to sort it out?